# Error: unexpected response Forbidden Issue with cubejs

Tags: node.js, npm, d3.js, cube.js

I am running the below command to create the service in cubejs but facing forbidden error.

Command : cubejs create d3-dashboard -d postgres

> npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@17.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi' npm
> ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path
> C:\work\d3-dashboard\node_modules@cubejs-backend\cubestore npm ERR!
> command failed npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c
> node bin/post-install npm ERR! Cube.js Cube Store Installer
> --------------------------------------- npm ERR! npm ERR! Error: unexpected response Forbidden npm ERR! at
> Object.downloadAndExtractFile
> (C:\work\d3-dashboard\node_modules@cubejs-backend\shared\src\http-utils.ts:80:11) npm ERR! at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) npm ERR! at
> C:\work\d3-dashboard\node_modules@cubejs-backend\cubestore\js-wrapper\src\post-install.ts:12:7
> npm ERR! npm ERR! Need some help?
> ------------------------------------- npm ERR! npm ERR! Ask this question in Cube.js Slack: https://slack.cube.dev npm ERR! Post an
> issue: https://github.com/cube-js/cube.js/issues
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\ramec\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-21T06_01_08_513Z-debug.log
>
> Cube.js Error ---------------------------------------
>
> Error: npm install --save-dev @cubejs-backend/server failed with exit
> code 1 at ChildProcess. (C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\cubejs-cli\src\utils.ts:14:16) at
> ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28) at ChildProcess.cp.emit
> (C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\cubejs-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16) at
> Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)

Answer (score 2):

add `CUBESTORE_SKIP_POST_INSTALL=true` to your environment variables as a quick workaround. this works if you don't want to use cubestore for the moment, otherwise wait for the issue to be fixed.

Comment: yes, it worked after setting environment variable and restart.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use [Docker-based setup](https://cube.dev/docs/getting-started/docker/).
Your issue may be related to GitHub limits. We use releases to store binaries for Cube Store, when npm/yarn runs post-install script we send a request to Github's API to fetch release’s assets. It works now.